# How do I stop 2 buttons doing the same job? In this case, they both scroll to the top

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 buttons that are placed on top of each other on my website. One is opens up a model and the other is used to scroll to the top.

I have one piece of code that does scroll to the top, fade in and fade out. 
However, both buttons seem to scroll to the top and I do not want this.

I have tried removing fade in, fade out, hide and show sections. How can I edit this piece of code to allow only the back to top button to scroll to the top, and both buttons to fade out when at the top and fade back in when I'm scrolling through the page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
            $('#back-to-top').fadeIn();
            $('#poll').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('#back-to-top').fadeOut();
            $('#poll').fadeOut();
        }
    });
    // scroll body to 0px on click
    $('#back-to-top').click(function () {
        $('#back-to-top').tooltip('hide');
        $('#poll').tooltip('hide');

        $('body,html').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 800);
        return false;
    });

    $('#back-to-top').tooltip('show');
    $('#poll').tooltip('show');

});
```

Comment: can you post the relevant html as well? preferably in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). I see only one click event, so basically it is "not possible" that the other button does the same (I assum you mean a button with id `poll`?). Probably there's something wrong with the html.

Comment: Hi thanks, Here is the fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/2boz374q/ (I hope this correct, never used it before)

I did some research into bootstrap and modal and found that I should wrap the modal around the button for it to work, if this is the problem.

Comment: I editted a bit, but seems to work like  a charm... check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/2boz374q/1/

Comment: Hey thanks for the input. Can I ask why you added a spacer div? I had a look at your code and my code, but I can't see what the difference was.

Comment: spacer is just there to trigger the scroll ;) and the other 'edits' are to include jquery and bootstrap. That's it

Comment: The solution didnt work for more, the both buttons still scroll to the top :(

Comment: it wasn't a solution, it was just there to make the fiddle work... if it does work in the fiddle, but does _not_ work on your own project, then there's something else what's causing the problems. I'm gonna vote to close now, as we don't have a minimal verifiable example and it seems you're not able to present us one...

Answer (score -1):

make sure that two buttons have different names and ids.

```
<button name="b1" id="id1">
<button name="b2" id="id2">
```

That distinguish html for javascript usually.

Comment: I can confirm both buttons have different ID's

Comment: do have names accordingly?

Comment: To be sure, add names: <a id="poll" name="p1" for two buttons.

Comment: `name` attribute is obsolete in html5 (it doesn't exist there). So better NOT use the `name` attribute at all... Furthermore, the name attribute does not effect selecting DOM elements or attaching events to them. So if you would add them, it's quite useless anyway.